# Change look of JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, custom-component

I have the following class in my Java project

```
    public class ComboBox extends JComboBox {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    ComboBox(){
        for(Component comp : this.getComponents()){
            if(comp instanceof AbstractButton){
                comp.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

This code change look of JComboBox, but after second, old JComboBox appear. My question is how to constantly revalidate JComboBox.

Comment: This code change look of JComboBox, but after second, old JComboBox appear. --> looks like as bug in your code

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you want to hide the arrow button of a `JComboBox`. In Swing architecture this work is delegated to a UI class (UI delegate) that is created on `Component` ctor by calling to `updateUI()` method.

As you are hidding the arrow button in ctor, may be the `updateUI()` method is begin called after.

I think that you could fix your code well removing the calls to `updateUI()` or hiding the arrow button at that point.

for example:

```
class ComboBox<T> extends JComboBox<T> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public ComboBox(){
        }

        @Override
        public void updateUI() {
            super.updateUI();
            hideArrowButton();
        }

        private void hideArrowButton() {
            for(Component comp : this.getComponents()){
                if(comp instanceof AbstractButton){
                    comp.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also you could write a UI Delegate that hides the arrow button:

```
class ComboUI extends MetalComboBoxUI {

    @Override
    protected JButton createArrowButton() {
        JButton arrowButton = super.createArrowButton();
        arrowButton.setVisible(false);

        return arrowButton;
    }

    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        return new ComboUI();
    }
}
```

And set it on your `JComboBox` by calling the `setUI()` method or setting it as default for all `JComboBox` by updating the `UIManager`

```
UIManager.put("ComboBoxUI", ComboUI.class.getName());
```

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html#modified_mvc for more info about Swing MVC and UI Delegates.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question. Is there any way to remove border of all components of JComboBox. For example, something like this comp.setBorder(null);